# Bi-directional magento theme

Tags: theme

Recently I bought a magento theme, Its currently LTR (Left-To-Right), but I would like use it in multilingual store which supports Engish (LTR) and Persian (RTL) languages.

Is there any rule for this condition in magento? for example in drupal each CSS files can have `[main-css]-rtl.css` version and in WordPress we can have `rtl.css` file to make theme Bi-directional.

Where should I start?

Comment: I never hear of something like this. Magentos support to problems outside of the US is not that big. Therefore I fear, there is nothing you can build on

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a standard option for Right-To-Left, you will have to rely on 3th party Themes.

The [Rtl Default Theme](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/rtl-default-theme.html) is free and might give you some basic CSS that you can use in your own theme.